# How to convert JArray to string

Tags: c#

I have a JArray like this:

jaFruits =  ["Apple","Pineapple","Banana","Orange"];

How to convert it into a string like below?

string strFruits -> "'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Banana', 'Orange'";

any help is appreciated.

thank you so much in advance.

Regards
Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something along these lines:

```
string strFruits = String.Join(", ",jaFruits.Select(m=>$"'{m}'"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] fruits= jaFruits.ToObject<string[]>();
var strFruits = String.Join(",", fruits);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject Method in order to extract the values/string from JArray and then loop the object to get the string you expected.

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ja = @"{""Col"": [ { ""Text"": ""select1"", ""Val"": ""select1"" }, { ""Text"": ""lastname"", ""Val"": ""lastname"" }]}";
            A js = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(ja);
            string s = "";
            foreach (var i in js.Col)
            {
                s += i.Val+";";
            }
            Console.Write(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1));
        }

        public class A
        {
            public List<B> Col { get; set; }
        }
        public class B
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public string Val { get; set; }
        }
```

Credits/reference @User-719153870 : [Microsoft Social Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/725cfc32-2ebe-4072-ae46-d63097e3b89c/how-can-i-get-the-values-from-a-jarray-to-form-a-string-?forum=aspcsharp)